# Parsing the output of Windows commands on non-English versions

Tags: windows, command-line, language

For a project I'm doing I need to run some Windows commands and then parse their outputs. In particular, the commands I'm interested in are:

- netstat
- netsh
- ipconfig
- arp

I've built my little system and everything works great.

Now I'm concerned about what happens if people try to use my system on a non-English version of Windows. I'm assuming that the output of these commands won't be in English, so some of the strings that I parse for won't be there.

How can I deal with this? Is there some way to force English output? If not, is there some easy way for me to find out what the output of netstat looks like in French (or ipconfig in Arabic?). I don't know how to even begin to install all of the possible versions, is there an easier way?

**More Info**

My system is not a batch file, but rather a Java program launching the Windows command.

Here's an example: I'd like to know what sort of wireless encryption my WiFi interface has. So I run netsh. Here's the output:

```
C:\Data>netsh wlan show interfaces

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
    GUID                   : d2c31baf-270c- ....
    Physical address       : 34:e6: ....
    State                  : connected
    SSID                   : PlinkY
    BSSID                  : c4:e9 ....
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Profile
    Channel                : 4
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 150
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 150
    Signal                 : 99%
    Profile                : PlinkY

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

I can parse through this to try to find the line called "Authentication" and look for whatever is after the colon. I'm guessing that if we're not on an English version of Windows, I'd never find the "Authentication" string as it would be something else.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: If you [edit] the question and provide the batch file you are using it will be much easier to offer advice.

Comment: I've updated my question above to provide more info. I don't have a batch file but I've given an example of what my needs are.

Comment: look into Windows WMI instead of launching external programs and parsing the output